# Is there an equivalent of GitHub releases in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Simply speaking, does Azure Devops have something that works very close to GitHub releases?

I would like to publish artifacts that are created during an Azure DevOps pipeline so that they be easily viewed and downloaded afterwards in a central location. The closest equivalent to what I'm looking for is how [GitHub releases](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/about-releases) work, where there is a web page listing out all the versions of the repository and the assets that can be downloaded for each version.

It seems to me that published artifacts within Azure DevOps pipelines are always tied to the run of the pipeline, and there isn't an easy way to see one list of artifacts that have been created in a historical view like GitHub releases provides, but maybe I'm missing something.

Azure Artifacts does not meet my needs because it is tied to particular packaging formats and is meant to be used for developer tooling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to publish artifacts that are created during an Azure
> DevOps pipeline so that they be easily viewed and downloaded
> afterwards in a central location.

As a workaround ,you can switch `Artifact publish location` to `A file share` in Publish Pipeline Artifacts task then specify your network drive folder path.

Specifying the path to the file share where you want to copy the files. The path must be a fully-qualified path or a valid path relative to the root directory of your repository. Publishing artifacts from a Linux or macOS agent to a file share is not supported.

[image]

Besides, there should be no other built-in hosting, I am afraid that Azure Artifact is the closest to your needs. `because it is tied to particular packaging formats` you can consider using [Universal Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=azuredevops).

Comment: I have considered this, although I would have to instead add a task to copy the artifacts to Azure blob storage since I'm using the SaaS Azure DevOps (not on-prem) where there isn't a file share available. Is there not anything more natively built-in to DevOps itself for hosting and listing the files though?

Comment: Besides, there should be no other built-in hosting, I am afraid that Azure Artifact is the closest to your needs. `because it is tied to particular packaging formats ` I think you can consider using [Universal Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=azuredevops).

Comment: Universal Packages might be good enough as they seem to be meant for storing arbitrary collections of files, I'll give them a try. Thanks!

Comment: I updated Universal Packages to the answer .  If the answer is helpful, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.